# Google Play App Publishing Issue

Tags: android, google-play

I have published my app revisions many times on Google Play. It usually takes 2 hours before the revision is available for download. This time it's 14 hours and counting despite the console saying it is published. Is anyone else seeing this?

Comment: Whats your app package?

Comment: Off Course I too face this kind of delay. It may happen some time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have published your app on Google Play then it can takes some hours or it can be taken full 24 hours Day for publishing app.

Answer (score 0):

So it eventually published - 22 hours in total.